# How to use a generating function to work out an infinite sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, generating-functions

I have the infinite sums:

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty k^2a^k \quad \text{and}\quad \sum_{k=0}^\infty ka^k$$

where, $\left\lvert a \right\rvert<1$. I was able to find the answers to the infite sums [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_series#Sums_of_powers), but I am interested on how I could use generating functions to get the same answer.

I am unsure of how to even begin this problem. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Generating functions are useful to make some algebra with sequences, and get concrete values of a sequence, but if you want just the limit of a partial sum (the "sum" of an infinite series is it) then I dont think that a generating function must be useful here because you are searching just the limit, not values of an infinite sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's consider the *[geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Geometric_power_series)*
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x^k=\frac{1}{1-x}
\end{align*}

> Differentiation and multiplication with $x$ results in
>   \begin{align*}
> \left(xD_x\right)\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x^k=x\sum_{k=0}^\infty kx^{k-1}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty kx^k
> \end{align*}
>
> We conclude by applying the operator $(xD_x)$ once and twice
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}kx^k&=(xD_x)\frac{1}{1-x}=\ldots=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}\\
> \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}k^2x^k&=(xD_x)^2\frac{1}{1-x}=\ldots=\frac{x(x+1)}{(x-1)^3}
> \end{align*}